# How to resize a window with Compiz?

Tags: command-line, bash, compiz

I would like to resize and place in the specific location a specific window using Compiz via command line or Java package.

On the input I would like to set

- tuple for top-left corner
- tuple for width-height size
- ID of window to update

It is possible?

Comment: Could you please add a little more detail? What *exactly* did you do, what did you want to achieve and what happened instead? Did you encounter any warning or error messages? Please reproduce them in their entirety in your question. You can select, copy and paste terminal content and most dialogue messages in Ubuntu. (see [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask))

Comment: I don't really know how compiz works, but maybe [Plugins/Resize](http://wiki.compiz.org/Plugins/Resize) helps?

Comment: Why on earth would you use compiz for that?

Comment: I tried to do that with `wmrctl`, but it has bug: window is not resized/located correctly. I thought Compiz can be a good candidate to replace `wmctrl`. Could you recommend something else to do that?

Comment: One hour ago, DavidFoerster wrote “*What exactly did you do, what did you want to achieve and what happened instead?*”, but you're mentioning this now, in a comment – seriously?

Comment: @Simon: At the risk of repeating myself: which *exact* `wmctrl` command(s) did you use and what *exactly* happened when you did?

Comment: What are the properties of the window that you tried or are trying to remove/resize? You can use `xprop` to find out about them.

Comment: This sounds indeed like a `wmctrl` bug – might be something with the wetware.

Answer (score 3):

`wmctrl` offers a way to change a window's size and position. To move a window with ID = 11 to 50,50 and resize it to 250,250, use:

```
wmctrl -ir 11 -e 0,50,50,250,250
```

About the argument of option `-r` the manpage says:

> This  argument specifies a window that is the target of an action. By
>   default the argument is treated as if were a string, and windows are
>                 examined until one is found with a title the contains the specified string as a substring. The substring matching is done in
>   a case insen‐
>                 sitive  manner. The -F option may be used to force exact, case sensitive title matching. The option -i may be used to
>   interpret the window
>                 target as a numeric window identity instead of a string.

About the argument of option `-e` the manpage says:

> A move and resize argument has the format 'g,x,y,w,h'.  All five components are integers. The first value, g, is the gravity
>   of  the  window, with 0 being the most common value (the default value for the window). Please see the EWMH specification for other
>   values. The  four remaining values are a standard geometry specification: x,y is the position of the top left corner of the
>   window, and w,h is the
>                 width and height of the window, with the exception that the value of -1 in any position is interpreted to mean that the 
>   current  geometry
>                 value should not be modified.

Read [`man wmctrl`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/wmctrl.1.html) for more information.

---

An alternative way is provided by `xdotool`. To move a window with ID = 11 to 50,50 and resize it to 250,250, use:

```
xdotool windowmove 11 50 50 windowsize 11 250 250
```

See [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/359311/246819) and of course [`man xdotool`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/xdotool.1.html) for details.

Comment: I know `wmctrl` and  `xdotool`, but in both of those programs have bugs. When you want to move window to 0,0 (`xdotool windowmove 11 0 0`), the window does not move exactly to 0,0, but around 20px ,20px. I thought resizing and changing location via Compiz can work without bugs and move window to correct place.
Or maybe I should try get access to lower layer, X11 for example?

Comment: Sorry, but I am **sure** `wmctrl` and `xdotool` work just fine. If you need help using them open up a new question and tell us what you wanted to do and what happened instead, and we will help.